# Expected Value in Simple Game

Tags: probability

The question I need help with is below. Here is what I've done:

There are 4 possible outcomes: (Player A says 1, Player b says 1) (Player A says 2, Player b says 2), (Player A says 1, Player B says 2), (Player A says 2, Player B says 1). So there are 4 outcomes, 2 of which leads to player A getting a point, and 2 of which give player B a point. So I said the expected value for A is .5, but the computer system kicks that back as wrong. Am I missing something obvious?

[image]

Comment: Maybe, the answer is 0 (because if A loses he gets -1)?

Comment: From the wording of the question, player A "wins 1 point from player B," it seems to me like they take the point from the other player. So 2 outcomes lead to player A winning a point, and 2 outcomes lead to player A (losing) giving a point to player B. So the expected value in that case might be 0.

Comment: Note that is says, "B wins one point **from** player A."

Comment: You are all correct. I wasn't realizing the players lose points. Seems so obvious now. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the question asks you to find the expected value that player $A$ will win, which is $0$ - this follows since you've established that both players have the same probability of winning and both win the same amount. More formally:

$\mathbb{E}[\text{winnings of A}]=\frac{1}{2}\cdot1+\frac{1}{2}\cdot(-1)=0$

where I used the law of total probability